# Run code if inside a specific category

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Hi there I'm trying to display html code on certain pages in Joomla 3.0 depending on what category they're in -  I've tried this but it won't work and displays nothing;

```
<?php $catid = JRequest::getInt('catid'); if ($catid == 14) {?>

HTML CODE GOES HERE

<?php } ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: have you echoed out $catid to make sure it is 14? Or if it even exists in the one of the request globals ($_GET,$_POST)

Comment: You should also upgrade to 3.1.5, several security issues have been patched since 3.0.x

Answer (score 1):

Rather than hardcoding this in to your site, just use Advance Module Manager and a Custom HTML module. This will make it trivial to change/add/delete what you want to display and where you want to display it.

First, create a menu item for each category if you don't already have one. If you do not want the links to show anywhere, create a new menu for the links and do not assign it to a module.

Next, install Advance Module Manager. For each category, create a new Custom HTML module with what you want to display. Then just assign the module to display for the menu item you created in the first step.

Comment: Thanks Brent, I'm using 3.1.5 I just said 3.0 out of habit apologies! My problem is the custom code I want to enter is the article title so in one category it displays; <h1>category - page title</h1> and in another it displays <h1>page title</h1> with two images to the right of it - I don't know of a way to display this info in a custom html module do you?